# Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'width': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am trying to implement useFrameProcessor from React native vision camera but when I try to use useFrameProcessor and run my App I am having an error or it crashes randomly, I tried to follow the documents.

Help if anyone knows how to solve this...!!!!

```
 import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {
  Camera,
  Frame,
  useCameraDevices,
  useFrameProcessor,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [cameraAccess, setCameraAccess] = useState(false);
  const camera = useRef(null);

  const askPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const getPermission = await Camera.getCameraPermissionStatus();
      if (getPermission === 'denied') {
        const reqPrmission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
        if (reqPrmission === 'granted') {
          setCameraAccess(true);
          console.log('Access granted');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect is called');
    askPermission();
  }, []);

  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.back;

  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame: Frame): any => {
    'worklet';
    console.log(frame, 'data');
  }, []);

  if (device == null && !cameraAccess) {
    console.log('camera not found');
    return <ActivityIndicator style={styles.sectionContainer} size={'large'} />;
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Camera
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        ref={camera}
        device={device}
        isActive={true}
        frameProcessorFps={5}
        frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 10,
    width: '100%',
  },
});'

export default App;
```

I want to call the useFrameProcessor for my App and print the console as per documents i have also added dependency worklets. above are dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^0.2.0"
  },
```